# How can I set the mac osx default button in tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am using TkInter to develop a simple application for Mac OSX in python.

I am wondering how to set the 'default button' for a dialog in tkinter. See the [human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BABCAJID) to see what this means.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Both the Button and ttk.Button widgets have a `default` attribute. Setting it to `"active"` should give you the visual appearance you are looking for. You will need toset the focus to that button and/or add a binding on `<Return>` to invoke the button.